# Bypass http authentication by using a reverse proxy

Tags: apache, authentication, mod-proxy

We are running a legacy web application which uses HTTP Authentication. I want to make this application available to some users but I do not want to expose the username/password and I don't want to expose the server the application is running on.

To solve this problem I intend to use mod_proxy. I made the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # SSL stuff goes in here
    ServerName "proxy.local"
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://admin:password@legacy.local:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://admin:password@legacy.local:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works, except for the part where users are still asked to type admin/password themselves.
Can I make Apache send the username/password provided in ProxyPassReserve and not ask the user for it? I could not find the answer in the [Apache mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Answer (score 3):

You will have to enable mod_headers and set http Authorization header before passing request from the mod_proxy.

Just base-64 encode the admin:password string and add RequestHeader directive to your configuration:

```
RequestHeader set Authorization: "Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ="


<VirtualHost *:443>
    # SSL stuff goes in here
    ServerName "proxy.local"
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://legacy.local:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://legacy.local:80/
    RequestHeader set Authorization: "Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ="
</VirtualHost>
```